# Migrating Gracenote Mobile API to Android Studio from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gracenote

I'm testing one application that listen to song and identify the song .For that i have used gracenote api for mobile client api and help available on Android [here](https://developer.gracenote.com/mobile-client-barebones-android-intro) and successfully implement it on the Eclipse but when i tried the same on the android studio it throws me the following error:

```
No implementation found for int com.gracenote.mmid.MobileSDK.FPXJNI.nativeInitialize() (tried Java_com_gracenote_mmid_MobileSDK_FPXJNI_nativeInitialize and Java_com_gracenote_mmid_MobileSDK_FPXJNI_nativeInitialize__)
```

I have followed each step and without any change it worked on Eclipse but not on Android Studio.
Following is the screen shot on android studio
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was bit hard task. I just complete my app in Eclipse and import it in Android studio but the native libraries causing me problem. So i spent time with them and searching for solution and at last insert jniLibs folder in app folder and it solved my problem.

Comment: Hi Chintan i am new to gracenote will you please help me i have integrated gracenote sdk , i am trying to get metadata  using finger print of mp3 file but i am always getting error message "couldn't find registration information"... please reply i need it.